# Android : Orientation : Find out if a device supports orientations change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I would like to know if an Android phone actually has an Orientation Sensor.
I doubt not all android phones screen changes with change in Orientation (like phones with qwerty keypad)

I have gone through the documentation and found a boolean method 'canDetectOrientation ()'
[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html#canDetectOrientation%28%29) 
But I found nothing mentioned in the description. Can anybody tell me if this is the 
method to find out if a device supports orientation changes .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look out in [Sensor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html) & [SensorManager](http://goo.gl/u4lVQ)

Comment: @rajpara : Looked into Sensor & Sensor Manager,all I could find there was to get orientation details etc,  couldn't find anything that helps finding out if a phone has orientation sensor present or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we pass `Type.All` in `getSensorList` function then we will get list of all available sensor.

Then we can traverse a list and fetch Sensor type of all sensor if we found Sensor type Orientation (integer value is 3) then we can conclude that that device has that sensor.

Below is code snippet for the same.

```
boolean OrientationSensorFound=false;
SensorManager mSensorManager;
Sensor mSensor;

mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
List<Sensor> mSensorList = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL );

for(int i=0;i<mSensorList.size();i++){
    // 3 is value for Orientation sensor
    if(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION==mSensorList.get(i).getType()){
        OrientationSensorFound=true;
        break;
    }
}
Log.i("Sensor Found", "Orientation found : "+OrientationSensorFound);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your time, I didn't go for 'Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION' as the documentation says 'This constant was deprecated in API level 8.' and suggests us to go for ' SensorManager.getOrientation()' instead.

Comment: Do you agree that sensor type value must be 3 every time ??

Comment: Yes, got your point now. Many thanks, that should do the job I guess, will try and let you know

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the actual android source code. Just follow the crumbs at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/OrientationEventListener.java#OrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation%28%29